# Using hashmap to start new activity(Android studio using Java)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to use a Hashmap to hold Intents so that i may be able to start new activities throughout my project. 
For example: Main Menu to options screen, options screen back to Main menu etc using buttons. 
I am really struggling when it comes to making this and i am not sure how to proceed from what i have done.
Can anyone shed some light on how to proceed? 
Thanks

Comment: add `Intent` in `onPost Execute`

Comment: Do you have some code implemented?

Comment: I have tried some code but i tend to get frustrated and delete it
ive answered a question below with a more specific idea if that helps, again sorry im very new

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do that. A much better approach is to create a static method `start()` in an Activity an pass in a context for example -

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
 public static void start(Context context){
  context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyActivity.class));
 }

 // rest of Activity code here
}
```

and then call `MyActivity.start(this)` from another activity that you want to call it from

Comment: I get you, though I need to use one class to call all the activities. The best way to describe it would be like a screen manager e.g. screenmanager.addscreen or screen manager.setscreen. Do you have any recommendations for that? like an array of intents perhaps? sorry if im making it complicated, im very new to android studio. Thanks